# NodeJS server not sending message

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

this is my first post here so I hope I do well.

So, for a school project I'm handling our game's networking and we have chosen to create a multiplayer fighting game where users are able to use their phones as controllers. **Originally,** we were going to use phone mobile browsers and so I had some crazy Websocket server, TCP server combination going on.

Since then, we have decided to use a Unity app on the phone instead which has removed the need for the Websocket server. Before I explain the steps, these are two Github gists of the relevant code snippets that you can open in other tabs in order for this to be a bit easier to follow:

NodeJS TCP Server: https://gist.github.com/JesseLeitch/dce3f51eea893ea5872c

Unity TCP Client: https://gist.github.com/JesseLeitch/59212d34a6fad41a2efc

Now, my problem:

I will walk through the process here:

1) I start up my NodeJS TCP server on my laptop.

2) I start up a Unity game, receiving a message from the server that it has connected.

3) My team mate starts up a Unity "game"(it's our controller) on his laptop that connects to the server with a successful connection message once again from the server.

4) My friend presses a button on the controller.

5) The button sends a message to the server. For example, "Jump".

6) **Here is where my problem arises**. What *should* happen is the server then sends the message down to the game, the message is processed within the OpenStream function and then it is passed off to a movement script. This is not happening. Nothing is being read in the game and I do not know why.

I know that the writing function is working fine because the console.log on line 14 is outputting properly with his command. What I am unsure of is why the c.write(d) is not *seemingly* working properly - especially because this worked previously when I was using our previous Game <-> TCP <-> WS <-> Mobile browser set-up.

Any help people can offer is **greatly** appreciated as I'm stumped and I haven't seemed to find anything relevant in my searching because the server seems to communicate fine except for this issue.

Thanks!

~Camel

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to verify the traffic being sent back and forth? That way you'd know for sure if `c.write(d)` is working properly.

Comment: The nodejs code you posted in github is working properly, you can use the  'nc' command to send data to the nodejs program and check if its working